# Are there any standard regulations for oral exams for universities in Bologna process?

Tags: exams, bologna-process

As described in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process),

> The Bologna Process is a series of ministerial meetings and agreements
>   between European countries to ensure comparability in the standards
>   and quality of higher-education qualifications.

Universities usually go through a series of supervisions to obtain the certificate that demonstrates the above mentioned quality of education.

These supervisions are, but not limited to, number of classrooms, regulations for exams, lab facilities, etc.

I am particularly interested in oral exam regulations. For instance, my former university had a strict rule:

> There must be at least three lecturers/professors during the oral
>   exam, and full voice recording is mandatory.

I wonder if such rule applies for all universities in the Bologna process, or my former university was being over cautious.

Comment: Looking at procedures for PhD defences might help you find your answer. (I'm unaware of any university that records defences.)

Comment: @user2768 I am not asking specifically about PhD defenses, but *any* oral exam.

Comment: No universal rules: oral exams during my studies were conducted in the examiner's office with no witnesses and no recording. Public PhD defenses are public, but not recorded either.

Comment: @corey979 can you show the reference?

Comment: UK vivas usually only have three attendees (two examiners and the student) so this rule cannot be universal

Comment: @MJeffryes But are those universities in Bologna process?

Comment: @padawan Any oral exam includes defenses... So you need only consider those to infer whether universities follow the Bologna process.

Comment: @padawan I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I'm aware, the Bologna process was a treaty between countries, not something that individual universities sign up for?

Comment: @user2768 I don't understand your reasoning. "Oral exams" is a superset of "PhD defenses." You are answering a more general question by referring to a subset.

Comment: @padawan Oral examinations are indeed a superset of defenses. I don't understand how I'm answering a more general question. Surely I'm asking a narrower question? This suffices to answer your question assuming the answer is negative, which is what MJeffryes has pointed out.

Comment: @MJeffryes Sorry, I misread your comment. However, that still does not mean that those universities are doing the correct thing. What I ask is an item in the code of conduct for universities if Bologna process.

Comment: @padawan What is more likely: All universities in the UK are failing to correctly implement the Bologna process, or that there are no rules about the number of faculty members present at oral exams? The UK procedure for oral exams is (as far as I know) quite different from other countries in Europe, which is further evidence against the possibility that the rules are harmonised.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks for the clarification. I understood your insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there are any Bologna-wide regulations regarding the conduct of oral exams.

In general, the Bologna process is designed to set up the means of making education "portable," not strictly uniform. Individual countries and schools are given wide latitude for how they internally implement the processes: for instance, just look at the wide of grading systems used throughout the EU.

As a counterexample to your question, I worked as a faculty member in Germany, and the rules varied between faculties, let alone universities. For instance, one or two professors could conduct the oral exam, notes were taken by a recorder, and the exam was rarely, if ever, recorded. The only situation where things got more complicated is if a person could fail out of the program by failing the oral exam, in which case having two professors, one of whom did not teach the subject, was required.